# How to give counterexample for given claim

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose $A_1,\dots,A_m$ be distinct $n\times n $ real matrices such that $A_iA_j=0$ for all $i\neq j$. Show that $m\leq n$.

I think this true because i tried for $3\times 3$ and $2\times 2$ case I got only $3$ and $2$ matrices with that property.

But given that this not true .

Can any one help me to find counterexample.

And what is best approach to tackle such problem.

Comment: Do you require that $A_i$ is never the zero matrix?

Comment: Ohh If I take that then I get counterexample Thanks ...But if we assume all A_i nonzero then is it possible

Comment: @MathLover What if $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are linearly independent? Are you sure that in the statement we have "distinct" matrices?

Comment: Yes Statement is distant Not Linearly Indepedent .

Comment: @RobertZ Sir If matrices are linearly indepdent then I this above statement is true .Is I am correct?

Comment: If $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are linearly independent, they form an orthogonal basis for a subset of $\mathbb M_{n\times n}$ for $m\leq n$.

Comment: @MathLover Should not be attached to the conditions that $A_iA_j \ne 0$ for $i=j$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix such that $A^{2}=0$. The the collection $\{cA:c\in \mathbb R\}$ has this property.